# html and dom button sequence creation

Tags: html, xml, dom, button, html-table

I'm trying to figure out how to use buttons to create new buttons that show up in front of the button that was selected. There are three buttons and an "insert" button. I want to be able to click button 1, then insert and have a new button appear before it. The same thing to occur for buttons 2 and 3.

I've noticed that with my code clicking the buttons automatically creates a new button at cell 0 in the table. I don't want the buttons to actually do anything but accept user input that can be used by the 'insert' button to place them there.

Please help, I'm stuck.

The code I have so far is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Button Sequence Creation</title>
<script>
function displayResult()
{
var firstRow=document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0];
var x=firstRow.insertCell();
x.innerHTML="New"
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Button Sequence Creation</h1>
<hr>
<table id = "myTable" border="1">
  <tr>
        <td>
    <input type="button" value="button1" name ="button1" onclick="displayResult()"></td>
        <td>
    <input type="button" value="button2" name ="button2" onclick="displayResult()"></td>
        <td>
    <input type="button" value="button3" name ="button3" onclick="displayResult()"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="displayResult()">Insert</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure how you would like the 'insert' button to function.  But the code below works.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Button Sequence Creation</title>
  <script>
    function displayResult(obj){
      var firstRow=document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0];
      var newButton = document.createElement('input');
      newButton.type = 'button';
      newButton.value = "New";

      var newTD = document.createElement('td');
      newTD.appendChild(newButton);

      obj.parentNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newTD, obj.parentNode);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Button Sequence Creation</h1>
  <hr>
    <table id = "myTable" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="button" value="button1" id="button1" name ="button1" onclick="displayResult(this)">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" value="button2" id="button2" name ="button2" onclick="displayResult(this)">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" value="button3" id="button3" name ="button3" onclick="displayResult(this)">
        </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   <br>
   <!--button type="button" onclick="displayResult()">Insert</button-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Paul, that is even better than what I was trying to do!. I see you created a parent - child relationship between the objects. Also you gave the buttons their own id. So instead of inserting a new cell you just created the newButton function, right?

Comment: Exactly.  Create a new button then append to the new td.  Then reference the parent you wish to insert the new DOM element as well and the child you want to insert before.